# Django QuerySet union operator are not commutative after annotated filter

Tags: python-2.7, django-queryset

... and return unexpected results (in Django 1.6.5)

My models.py

```
class Member(models.Model):
    ...
class Donation(models.Model):
    year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    cheque_amount = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    donor = models.ForeignKey(Member)
    ...
class SpecialTitle(models.Model):
    chair_title = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    member = models.OneToOneField(Member)
    ...
```

I'd like the union of the two querysets in one of my admin filters

```
donors = queryset.filter(
    donation__year__exact=2014
).annotate(sum_donation=Sum('donation__cheque_amount')).filter(sum_donation__gte=1000)

chairs = queryset.filter(specialtitle__chair_title__iendswith='Chair')
```

Here is the puzzling part (in Django manager shell)

```
>>> donors | chairs == chairs | donors
False
>>> donors.count(); chairs.count()
189
17
>>> (donors | chairs).count(); (chairs | donors).count()
193
291
>>> (donors | chairs).distinct().count(); (chairs | donors).distinct().count()
193
207
```

And none of them are the correct results. I'd expect a set operation to be

```
>>> set(donors) | set(chairs) == set(chairs) | set(donors)
True
>>> set(donors) & set(chairs) == set(chairs) & set(donors)
True
>>>
```

And they return the correct results. However, Django admin filter demands a QuerySet, not a python set (or list)

Why is this? How do I get a proper union of Django QuerySet (of the same type) after annotated filter?
Thank you.

Comment: I just encountered a similar problem -- a | b != b | a.  Looks like a HAVING clause for a is also getting applied to b, where I expected independence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I had no other choice but to use the python set union operator and hit the database again for the desired result.

```
donors = queryset.filter(
    donation__year__exact=2014
).annotate(sum_donation=Sum('donation__cheque_amount')).filter(sum_donation__gte=1000)

chairs = queryset.filter(specialtitle__chair_title__iendswith='Chair')

result = queryset.filter(pk__in=[person.id for person in set(donors) | set(chairs)])
```